# Using transform property in :hover and @keyframes for same div

Tags: css, html

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: anim 1s forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes anim{
    0%{transform: scale(1.2);opacity:0;}
    100%{transform: scale(1);opacity:1;}
}
div:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I'm having troubles with some code and transform property.

I have an entrance animation on a div. But my hover animation doesn't work, so it looks like that it doesn't because I already used "transform" inside the animation.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: it looks like you hover animation is also working.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the `transform` by adding`transition` to the `div`'s transform

```
/* property name | duration | timing function */
transition: transform 1s ease-in;
```

In your case

```css
@keyframes anim{
  0%{transform: scale(1.2);opacity:0;}
  100%{transform: scale(1);opacity:1;}
}
div:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
div{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: anim 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wskf9g2r/)**

**[Transition - MDN - DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)**